# Randomly mapping numbers

Tags: random, mapping

Is there a way to *iterate* through a large contiguous set of numbers (let's say 0 through 10^9) in random order, whilst ensuring I encountered every one of them in the end? Let's say that the numbers are large enough that shuffling an array isn't feasible:

```
 a = range(10**9); random.shuffle(a); # :(
```

I imagine this is impossible without some kind of perfect hashing algorithm (with zero collisions?).

So let me add as a mitigating circumstance that I don't need the mapping to actually 'truly' random though. It just has to have a nice 'spread'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a customized [linear congruential generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator#Period_length) whose modulus is the range you wish to iterate over.  If you conform to the three requirements of the Hull-Dobell Theorem (specified in the "Period Length" section of the linked Wikipedia article) your generator will iterate through every value before cycling.  To terminate, check the current iterate's generated value for equality to the initial value.

Comment: I was hoping someone could point me at something theoretically founded :) . Let me check.

Comment: LCG's are very well theoretically founded. Not sure what your objection is to something that has a theorem proving that the results will hop around through every possible value before repeating...

Comment: Yes they are, I think you got me wrong. What I was saying is: "I was hoping for your answer, thanks!" ;)

Comment: Ah. I misunderstood your comment to be an objection.  Apologies.

Comment: Finding this 'a' is going to be kind of tricky, no? Or is simply `a = m + 1` ok?

Comment: Finding `a` can be a real PITA if `m` has lots of factors.  Life is much easier if `m` is prime.  Using `a=1` and `c=1` always works, but is clearly not what you want ;)

Comment: In addition: take the first prime above your range as the modulus. Thus you can find good parameters more easily. And during enumeration, just drop all numbers above your range. Since the prime is very close, the "overhead" is neglectable.

Answer (score 0):

Heres a wiki page on shuffling using the Fisher-Yates shuffling algorithm

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle

Well, if you're using Java.. it is that easy.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html

if not, I'd suggest looking at this:

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/shuffle-a-given-array/

and if THAT doesn't work...

http://goo.gl/LkqffR

Comment: I actually don't want to just shuffle an array. Maybe I should have been more explicit. I want to iterate through the numbers in random order without keeping the whole thing in memory.

Comment: Oh I understand what you want.. I don't know to be honest. I'll see if I can come up with something though